# What is the current state of the art re: bedroom ceiling soundproofing?

Tags: sound-proofing, bedroom

I purchased a condo recently. I can hear every step the neighbors upstairs take, which wakes me up at inopportune hours. A pretty common experience, I'm sure.

What is the most effective way to throw money at the problem? The obvious option is paying a contractor for soundproofing; this is very expensive (I was quoted $35/ square foot) but seems likely to work. They would install a second ceiling and add layers of soundproofing.

Is there a better, more cash efficient way to do this?

Possibilities I am aware of, but haven't weighed:

- modifying the upstairs neighbor's flooring
- creating a box around my bed
- DIYing the ceiling modifications

EDIT: This question was closed because of similarity to a question about soundproofing walls. However, soundproofing needs for walls and ceilings are widely different, and the answers are not entirely relevant.

Comment: There are dozens of soundproofing questions here, you can pick and choose ideas from any of them.

Comment: If you're really looking for something done inside your own unit: decoupling the ceiling boards from the floor joists with resilient mounting will help. But that means completely replacing the ceiling in the affected room(s). Big investment for something that you will mostly learn not to pay attention to; I would advise waiting at least a year to see if it still bothers you, unless you're building a recording studio.

Answer (score 1):

> *modifying the upstairs neighbor's flooring*

That is the normal solution. My understanding is that in many rentals people are *required* to have carpeting in most of the apartment, excluding bathroom and kitchen, primarily to help with noise. The advantage of carpeting, particularly with thick padding, is that it *prevents* the noise in the first place. Anything you do on your ceiling will be trying to *block* a noise that already exists, which is a harder thing to do.

However, in condos normally the rules for what you do inside your apartment, including how you finish the walls, floors and ceilings, are up to the owner and not dictated by management. The colors you can paint the outside of your door to the common area may be specified, but inside your walls everything is up to you.

If your neighbor does not have carpeting in the room above your bedroom, they are not likely to want to pay for it. They *might* be willing to put in carpeting if you sponsor it, but even that is not guaranteed - depending on how they use the room or other personal preferences they may not want carpet. For example, if they have a pet they may prefer to not have carpeting to make cleanup (hair and other things) easier.

But I would try a friendly conversation with the neighbor and see if that gets you anywhere.